# Increase PHP date with nth week

Tags: php

Trying to pass a variable to increase week, not working. Actualy works with increase day.

```
 $n = 1;
    $incrdate = strtotime("2016-03-14" .' +$n week');
    echo date("Y-m-d", $incrdate );
```

Comment: It won't display the value of `$n` in single quotes, it will literally process `$n` as a string. Switch to double quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Use double quotes:

```
$incrdate = strtotime("2016-03-14 +$n week");
```

The problem is, your original variable $n was inside single quotes, which was parsed **literally** by PHP. For example:

```
$n = 5;
$t = "2016-03-14" . ' +$n week';
echo $t;
```

will output:

```
2016-03-14 +$n week
```

but

```
$n = 5;
$t = "2016-03-14" . " +$n week";
echo $t;
```

will output:

```
2016-03-14 +5 week
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `$n` inside the double quotes:

**Example:**

```
$n = 1;
$incrdate = strtotime("2016-03-14 +$n week");
echo date("Y-m-d", $incrdate ); // 2016-03-21
```

For better understanding try this example:

```
$n = 1;
echo "No: $n"; // this will print "No: 1"
echo 'No: $n'; // this will print "No: $n"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$date = "2016-03-12";

$n  =   3;

$future_date_ts = strtotime($date . " +".$n." week");

echo $future_date = date('d/m/y', $future_date_ts);
```

Hope this helps.

Peace! xD